# Can BufferedReader.read(char[], int, int) return 0?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Can `BufferedReader.read(char[], int, int)` return `0`?
If so in what situations?

I know that it returns `-1` at `EOF` and the number of read characters otherwise.

But is there a possibility that i read `0` characters while not at `EOF`?

Comment: I suppose if you called this with a len of 0, it might return 0. But why would you do this? Otherwise, no it would never return 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the third parameter (`len`) is 0, `read` will return immediately, and returns 0.

In **all other circumstances**, it is not possible*, because the `read` method (of both Reader and InputStream) is specced as follows:

- Do not return 0, even if there aren't (currently) any bytes/chars to return - wait (block) until some bytes/chars are available.
- If no bytes/chars are ever going to happen (this can only be concluded if the stream/reader is *closed*), then return -1.

Thus, 0 is impossible. Except if you explicitly say you want no bytes, which is a complete no-op (this doesn't test for 'availability' either, you can't really do that, if you want to know if bytes will be read if you call read, you're going to have to read them. Even `available()` doesn't quite do this).

*) In the end `Reader` and `InputStream` are interfaces and can therefore be implemented by anything, and any implementation can decide to return 0 even if `len` is not zero. However, such an implementation **is broken** because it does not adhere to the specification of InputStream and Reader. I am not aware of any core libraries (in package `java....`) that are such a broken implementation.